# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '''''''''' for column 'username' at row 1

Tags: laravel

When I use `" ' \` characters it shows  QueryException error.

How I can fix this error ?

```
Site::create([
            'title' => $request->title ,
            'url' => $request->url ,
            'username' => $request->credit ,
            'credit' => $request->credit
        ]);
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Check data type for `username` in MySQL server. Data type for username will be varchar

Comment: If i wanna to use charactor and dont show this error what's best way ? thanks

Comment: Normally for username you can use `varchar` and for long text you can use `text`.  Read more about mysql datatype from the link  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Comment: Show your migration schema